# How do I get an equipped tool in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I'm trying to code a shotgun in Roblox Studio. The code isn't working because its not getting the gun. When it activates, the gun should be equipped.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to get the gun from the player's character, including ":WaitForChild" and for loops, but they never end up working.
Here is my code:

```
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local function getEquippedTool(player: Player): Tool?
    local character = player.Character
    if not character then
        print("no character")
        return nil
    else
        local shotgun = character:WaitForChild("Shotgun")
        if not shotgun then
            print("no shotgun")
            return nil
        else
            print("success")
            return shotgun
        end
    end
    
    end

replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("ShotgunShoot").OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,part,pos,damage)
    print("Server: Triggered")
    local char = plr.Character
    local tool = getEquippedTool(plr)
    if tool == nil then 
        print("tool doesnt exist")
    else
        print(tool.Name)
        local handle = tool:WaitForChild("Handle")
        if part then
            print("part=true")
            if part.Parent and part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local humanoid = part.Parent.Humanoid
                humanoid:TakeDamage(damage)
                print("HIT")
            else
                print("MISS")
                local bullet = Instance.new("Part")
                bullet.Size = Vector3.new(0.1,0.1,0.1)
                bullet.Position = pos
                bullet.BrickColor = BrickColor.Black()
                bullet.Anchored = true
                bullet.CanCollide = false
                bullet.Parent = workspace
                game.Debris:AddItem(bullet, 5)
            end
        end
        if handle:FindFirstChild("ShotgunSound") then
            local sound = handle.ShotgunSound
            sound:Play()
        end
    end
end)
```

Can someone help me fix this?
EDIT: To clarify, the function `getEquippedTool()` is returning `nil` and I want it to return `player.Character.Shotgun` which I know is equipped when running the script.